# Searching custom nodes' by field in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-nodes, drupal-search

Using Drupal on a project which I made custom node types in using the CCK. I want to be able to search the specific node based on a custom field the node has. So let's say I have this node type Article which has a field "myfield", I want to be able to search for Articles based on the myfield field. I understand the default search module allows for searching of node types using the type:MyNodeType in the search, but I did not see any way to limit which fields are searched. Any tips? Is this something that is going to get crazy? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default search cannot filter by specific fields.

You have a couple options.

- Write custom code that filters again the actual fields in the database.
- Use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module, which lets you filter against specific fields.
- Install the [ApacheSolr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) search engine, which can filter against specific fields.

  - This is a fairly complex thing to install.
  - If you're comfortable installing it, though, it's a better and more flexible search than the other two options.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [CCK Facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_facets) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> CCK Facets is a bundle of modules that integrate with [Faceted Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/faceted_search) to expose [Content Construction Kit (CCK)](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck) fields as facets. This allows users to browse field values and to filter search results with those values.
>
> The supported CCK field types are:
>
> - Text
> - Number
> - Node Reference
> - User Reference
> - Date
> - Datestamp

Answer (score 0):

I use the Search API and Search API DB modules along wth Views for this.

This is a nice [how to article](http://webwash.net/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-1-how-create-search-pages).